# Find matches in different indices in String. Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I have two lines of the same length. I need to get the number of letters that match as letters and have different index in the string (without nesting loop into loop). How I can do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and expected output?

Comment: `(ABCD, DCBA) = 4`

`(ABCD, ACCD) = 1`  (B and C)

`(AAAA, BBBB) = 0`

`(ABBA, BAAB) = 4` (each letter from the first line is contained in the second, but not in the desired position)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko
I tried this construction
`str1.toList().intersect(str2.toList()).size`
and then subtract the number of complete matches (matched symbol and index)

But (ABBA, BAAB) return 2 because  intersect return Set of matched elements

Comment: What would you expect from (ABAA, BAAB)? The only letter that matches exactly is at index 2. But for all other letters the respective other word contains this letter at a different index. What about (AAAB, BCDA)? No letter matches exactly, but each of the for letters from the first word is contained in the second word, and two of the letters from the second word are contained in the first word.

Comment: @derpirscher
I expect 3 from (ABAA, BAAB). A_0 not full match, but we have A in str2. B_1 is similar. A_3 full match and not taken into result. A_4 is similar as A_0 and B_1

Comment: @Ta3ik What about the second example from my comment  (AAAB, BCDA)? If the answer is 4, what would you expect from  (BCDA, AAAB)? If the answer is still 4, why?

Comment: @derpirscher (AAAB, BCDA) A_0, A_1, A_2 partial match with A_3 from str2. B_3 with B1 (str2). Answer 4. (BCDA, AAAB) - B_1 (str1)- B_4(str2) and A_4(str1) - A_1 (or A_2, or A_3) (str2). Answer 2.

Comment: OK, so in fact, you need "*the number of characters from the first string, that are also contained in the second string but at a different index*"

Comment: @derpirscher You're right. My mistake has to do with the fact that this is my first day here. And my English is not completely good, so I still make mistakes in the formulation of my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following function work for you?

```
fun check(s1: String, s2: String): Int {
    var count = 0
    s2.forEachIndexed { index, c -> 
        if (s1.contains(c) && s1[index] != c) count++
    }
    return count
}
```

See it working [here](https://pl.kotl.in/mzi9UL7Ay)

Edit:
Alternatively, you could do it like this if you want a one-liner

```
val count = s1.zip(s2){a,b -> s1.contains(b) && a != b}.count{it}
```

where `s1` and `s2` are the 2 strings

Comment: Your function is not commutative (not sure if this is a requirement, but I'd expect it to be). Ie `check("BAAB", "AABC") == 2` but `check("AABC", "BAAB") == 3`

Comment: @derpirscher i actually expect that it is not supposed to be commutative. I'm suspecting this is for a mastermind kind of game to determine the amount of white pegs

Comment: I don't want to badmouth your anwser. Nobody knows what OP really wants. Just wanted to point out, that there are might be different expected results for that question. And your approach doesn't meet my interpreations. But by no means I want to imply my interpreation is correct and yours is wrong

Comment: @derpirscher no worries. I didn't see it as badmouthing. I understand your view and you could be right :). It's up to the OP whether my answer is the intended result

Comment: From the lates comment of OP, it seems, your interpretation is the correct one ;)